# enabling newly installed magento extension (facebook connect) what now?

Tags: extensions, facebook

I have followed the instructions to a T here on how to properly install a Magento extension. http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-extensions-magento-extension-installation-guide/

The extension in question is the [Magento Facebook Connect](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-connect-and-like.html) for Facebook login capabilities. The extension key seemed to work successfully upon pasting it into extension key field. Afterwards I got a small success message and scrolled down seeing the terminal frame act like it was a success. Then following the instructions in the above link, I simply hit refresh. Now, under '`Manage Existing Extensions`' **I see the facebook extension in there. But what now? How do I enable it?**

The small drop-down next to the extension, just has two options. Re-install or uninstall? How do I configure it and what do I do now to allow the facebook login functionality. For Wordpress, Drupal and other CMS's it typically just appears near the default login options. How do I enter my Facebook app ID and get this going?

```
Note: // There is no documentation to be found on this Facebook extension so any suggestions would be rad.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is you extension's user guide - http://store.belvg.com/media/Facebook_Connect_and_Like_Free_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for taking a look however where I found the free version here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-connect-and-like.html It only provides the extension key, it doesn't provide a .zip file, possibly this is for a different or premium version?